# Ordenar um Array de Hash em Ruby - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: array, ruby, hash

Minha pergunta é sobre ordenar uma hash dentro de array em Ruby.

Estou aprendendo a programar em ruby, meu primeiro contato com programação, estou exercitando fazendo o consumo de uma api.
Eu consegui chegar até onde queria, que era pegar o nome dos clubes a posição e imprimir.
Meu próximo objetivo é ordenar os clubes por posição, porém utilizando o (.sort) sempre retorna erro (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)

a api que estou consumindo está nesse https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/clubes
que basicamente retorna um hash.

```rb
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

url = 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/clubes'

resp = RestClient.get "#{url}"

clubes = JSON.parse(resp.body)

tabela = []
  for chave, valor in clubes 
    nome = valor["nome"]
    posicao = valor["posicao"]

    if posicao != nil
     tabela.push [:clube=>nome, :classificacao=>posicao]

    puts "O nome do time é #{nome} e a posição é #{posicao}º"
    end
  end

res = tabela.sort_by { |item| item[:classificacao] }

puts res
```

Answer (score -1):

Fiz umas modificações no codigo, transformei a tabela de Array para Hash para que ficasse melhor para usar o sort. Depois apenas

````rb
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

url = 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/clubes'
resp = RestClient.get "#{url}"
clubes = JSON.parse(resp.body)
data = {} # Dados iniciais dos clubes

for chave, valor in clubes
    nome = valor['nome']
    pos = valor['posicao']
    if pos != nil
        data[nome] = nome
        data[nome] = pos
    end
end

data = data.sort{|x, y| x.last <=> y.last} # Usando sort para verificar se o valor x anterior é menor igual ou maior que y anterior e adicionando na hash data já sortido
data.each{|k, v| puts "[#{v}] #{k} Posicao: #{v} "} # Fatiando a hash data deixando tudo bonitinho para imprimir```
````